# yeoman install [package] installs in /app/component

Tags: javascript, yeoman, bower

From what I understand, running `$ yeoman install backbone` should download the raw source for Backbone into a folder named components in the root of your project and move just the working copy of the file into `/app/scripts/vendor`. This way you've got the documentation for Backbone but the full repository isn't clogging up your application's codebase. However, my experience is it downloads the raw source- documentation and all- to `/app/components/`. Am I doing this wrong, or do I just need to manually move these to `/app/scripts/vendor`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, looks like I've just found an answer for this situation. As you said, Yeoman installs everything into /components and into app/components. The idea is you don't need those folders to be commited to your repository, as well as you don't need to always have those dependencies scripts in your scripts/vendor folder.

Installing dependencies is the thing that everyone should do on their local machine after downloading/checking out the project from your repository. That's better to write all the dependencies into components.json file in the root of the project. Like so:

```
{
    "dependencies" : {
        "backbone" : null
    }
}
```

That means your project has a dependency on current version of Backbone.js. After doing this, you can just execute

```
$ yeoman install
```

and each dependency will be downloaded into the components folder.

Next, you should use any build system for your project. As for me, I use require.js and then compile into one minified script file. So, you write your code basing on the scripts from the components library, then build it, and then there is no more dependency on the components, 'cause everything is already in just built script file.

When somebody wants to work on your project he will need to first install yeoman, run "yeoman install" and he is ready to go. This flow makes web development more like any other kind of software development with package management, dependencies, compiling etc.

If my answer is not good enough, try watching [this video from NetTuts+](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/installing-dependencies-and-requirejs-shims/), it explains everything.

Good coding!

Comment: Thanks for the the answer and the link to the video. It seems that `components.json` is a lot like the `Gemfile` in Rails? This is all really exciting. At first I thought this was weird, but now that I see what they're doing, I really like the separation. :) Thanks!

Comment: You are right about the similarity to Gemfile. I also like that client side development workflow is moving towards the principles used in server-side. It helps avoiding mess in the project structure. Good luck!